# Why do I get Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: unexpected token ',' when importing libraries using IronPython

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, ironpython

I'm using IronPython v 2.7.8.1 in VS 2017. I've installed Python27, 36 and 37. I've tried switching between the various environments in VS. I've tried adding the search paths to the libraries of these installs. The python code will work if I run it in the interpreter. Trying to run the same code in VS throws: "**Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: unexpected token ','** ". If I test a python script that doesn't include imports it will work? Is there a specific way python has to be installed to work IronPython? This is the C# Code:

```
class CallPython
{        
    public void PatchParameter(string parameter)
    {            
        var FilePath = (@"C:\Users\Pac\Downloads\MvcAuth\MvcAuth\TwurlPy\TwurlPy\SendDirectMsg.py");
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine(); // Extract Python language engine from their grasp
        ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\Pac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib");
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\Pac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages");

        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        var scope = engine.CreateScope(); // Introduce Python namespace 
        (scope)
        var d = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "text", text},
            { "userID", userID},                
        }; 
        // Add some sample parameters. Notice that there is no need in 
        // specifically setting the object type, interpreter will do that part for us 
        // in the script properly with high probability

        scope.SetVariable("params", d); // This will be the name of the 
        // dictionary in python script, initialized with previously created .NET 
        // Dictionary
        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(FilePath); 
        // Load the script
        object result = source.Execute(scope);
        parameter = scope.GetVariable<string>("parameter"); // To get the 
        // finally set variable 'parameter' from the python script
        return;
    }
}
```

This is the Python script. If I comment out the import statements it works using IronPython, but of course I need them...

```
import twitter
import requests
import sys

parameter = "test"

def SendDM(text, userID, access_token, access_secret):
    consumer_key = 'YkopsCQjEXccccccccccccccccccZvA9yy'
    consumer_secret = 'TQVCoccccccccccccccccccct7y8VfmE'
    access_token_key = access_token
    access_token_secret = access_secret

    api = twitter.Api(
        consumer_key=consumer_key,
        consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
        access_token_key=access_token_key,
        access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

    send_msg = api.PostDirectMessage(text, user_id=userID)

    print (send_msg)

    return


SendDM(text, userID, access_token, access_secret)
```